# Gitlab nginx - Unable to stop https redirect

Tags: ssl, https, redirect, gitlab

Today I tried to enable SSL for a gitlab instalation so I made the following changes in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
external_url 'https://our.server'
nginx['redirect_hhtp_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/our.server.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/our.server.key"
```

after some more struggle it finally worked actually and I was redirected always to https://our.server and could see that the page was encrypted.

**But**
The problem started when I wanted to revert it.

Something didn't work correctly because git always throw an error about the SSL certificate (though I also have configured the CA cert in git global).

So I wanted to make rollback to the former gitlab.rb looking like this (only the according parts)

```
external_url 'http://our.server'
# nginx['redirect_hhtp_to_https'] = false
# nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{node['fqdn']}.crt"
# nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/#{node['fqdn']}.key"
```

ofcourse after running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart` I expected now, everything would be back to "normal".

But I keep being redirected from http://our.server to https://our.server where ofcourse nothing responds. -> In the moment nobody can access/use the gitlab server anymore!

**How can I stop gitlab being redirected to https?**

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by another user was removed so I'll answer my own question here:

It he/she suspected that it might have to do something with [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

So to check I switched from Firefox to Chrome, entered my http adress (http://our.server) and it worked.

-> All I had to do in Firefox was going to `about:preferences#privacy` and under `history` click on `latest history` and delete the history of today (since I started at sometime in the morning)